# External image links in Electron do not open in an external browser

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm using this code to open external links in a browser outside of Electron. It works fine if text is written after the desination :

```js
 let shell = require('electron').shell
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'A' && event.target.href.startsWith('http')) {
    event.preventDefault()
    shell.openExternal(event.target.href)
  }
})
```

However, if an image is set as the link it doesn't work at all and opens in the Electron browser:

```html
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">
<img src='image1.jpg'></img>
</a>
```

How can I get an image link to open in an external browser in Electron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're listening for clicks on the document and then only checking `event.target`. As you have found out, if the click happens on a child element (for example, an image) inside the link, then `event.target` points to that child element, and you won't detect that the link was clicked.

This is one of the places jQuery comes in handy. Something like [`$(document).on('click', 'a', ...)`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) is fairly simple to deal with.

But you don't have to use jQuery. Because Electron uses Chromium, the click events have a non-standard attribute called `path`. That attribute is an array of parents, going up the DOM, all the way to body, document, and finally global. You can run [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on this array to check if any element happens to be a link, and then return that link to your event handler to deal with.

Here's what that looks like:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const link = getLink(event);

  if (link) {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert('caught: ' + link.href);
  }
});

function getLink(event) {
  return event.path.find(($el) => {
    if ($el.tagName === 'A' && $el.href.startsWith('http')) {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  });
}
```

```html
<p>
  Image link:
  <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">
    <img src='https://placehold.it/100x100' />
  </a>
</p>

<p>
  Text link:
  <a href="https://example.com">Test link</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using your first suggestion, using this code: 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.imagelink').click(function(){
   shell.openExternal("http://www.stackoverflow.com")  
    });
});